# How to display PGM image using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, pgm

I'm trying to load and display a .PGM image using OpenCV(2.4.0) for C++.

```
void open(char* location, int flag, int windowFlag)
{
    Mat image = imread(location, flag);
    namedWindow("Image window", windowFlag);
    imshow("Image window", image);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

I'm calling open like this:

```
open("./img_00245_c1.pgm", IMREAD_UNCHANGED, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
```

The problem is that the image shown when the window is opened is darker than if I'm opening the file with IrfanView.
Also if I'm trying to write this image to another file like this:

```
Mat imgWrite;
imgWrite = image;
imwrite("newImage.pgm", imgWrite)
```

I will get a different file content than the original one and IrfanView will display this as my function displays with imshow.

Is there a different flag in imread for .PGM files such that I can get the original file to be displayed and saved ?

**EDIT:** Image [pgm file](http://www.filedropper.com/img00941c1)

**EDIT 2 :** Remarked that: IrfanView normalizes the image to a maximum pixel value of 255 . 
In order to see the image clearly using OpenCV I should normalize the image also when loading in Mat. Is this possible directly with OpenCV functions without iterating through pixels and modifying their values ?

Comment: Maybe Irfanview is automatically normalising, i.e. contrast stretching your image and OpenCV is not... maybe try saving a normalised, contrast-stretched image in Irfanview and loading that into OpenCV, or contrast stretching a dark one in OpenCV before displaying it.

Comment: maybe you could find the answer [here ( take a look COMPATIBILITY )](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html). could you give a link to your PGM file ?

Comment: I've added a link to the photo !

Comment: The link is to a PNG file.

Comment: Try now, the site were I uploaded changed the file....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the way data are *loaded*, but in the way they are *displayed*.

Your image is a `CV_16UC1`, and both `imshow` and `imwrite` normalize the values from original range `[0, 65535]` to the range `[0, 255]` to fit the range of the type `CV_8U`.

Since your PGM image has `max_value` of `4096`:

```
P2        
1176 640  // width height
4096      // max_value
```

it should be normalized from range `[0, 4096]` instead of `[0, 65535]`.
You can do this with:

```
Mat img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
img.convertTo(img, CV_8U, 255.0 / 4096.0);

imshow("Image", img);
waitKey();
```

---

Please note that the values range in your image doesn't correspond to `[0, 4096]`, but:

```
double minv, maxv;
minMaxLoc(img, &minv, &maxv);

// minv = 198
// maxv = 2414
```

So the straightforward normalization in `[0,255]` like:

```
normalize(img, img, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX);
img.convertTo(img, CV_8U);
```

won't work, as it will produce an image *brighter* than it should be.

---

This means that to properly *show* your image you need to know the `max_value` (here `4096`). If it changes every time, you can retrieve it parsing the `.pgm` file.

Again, it's just a problem with *visualization*. Data are correct.

Comment: I would like to support this answer. I just converted a 16 bit pgm to a 16 bit tif using opencv (simply calling imread(..., -1), imwrite(...)). After opening both images with two different tools (IrfanView and the Beyond Compare image viewer), both showed differences between the two files. But when I reopened the two images with opencv, the pixel values were identical. You have to take into account that a lot of image processing tools do not properly support 16-bit images. So it's indeed often the case that the data is correct, but the visualization is not.